# How can I get started with creating a map of a country, not the world? (Data visualization)

Tags: python, module, data-visualization, visualization

I have looked extensively on the internet but I cannot seem to find a way to create only a map of a country! Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple method that will also introduce you to the wonderful world of GeoPandas:

```
import geopandas
import geoplot
myCountry = "Italy"
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
thisCountry = world.query('name == "{}"'.format(myCountry))
ax = geoplot.polyplot(
    thisCountry, 
    edgecolor='None', figsize=(7, 8)
)
geoplot.polyplot(thisCountry, edgecolor='gray', ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]

To get the list of all country names:

```
world.name.values
```

If you want really nice maps, you can search for "open data gis" for your country of interest, an you'll be able to download shape files which can create really wonderful maps.

e.g.
https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/a883eb14-0c0e-45c4-b8c4-b54c4a819edb

[image]

Good intro here:
https://towardsdatascience.com/a-beginners-guide-to-create-a-cloropleth-map-in-python-using-geopandas-and-matplotlib-9cc4175ab630

Good course here:
https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/use-data-open-source-python/intro-vector-data-python/